# Form elements are not shown?

Tags: php, zend-framework, forms, rendering

Created Form in **projectfolder/application/forms/Login.php**

```
class Form_Login extends Zend_Form {

    public function _construct() {

        $this->setMethod('post');

        $elements = array();

        $element = $this->addElement('text', 'username');
        $element->setLabel('Username');
        $elements[] = $element;

        $element = $this->addElement('password', 'password');
        $element->setLabel('Password');
        $elements[] = $element;

        $this->addElements( $elements );

        $this->setElementDecorators( array( 'ViewHelper' ) );

    }
}
```

Accessing Form in **myproject/application/controllers/AuthenticationController.php**

```
public function loginAction() {
   $this->view->heading = 'Login';
   $this->view->form = new Form_Login();
}
```

in **login.phtml**

```
<h1><?= $this->heading; ?></h1>
<?= $this->form; ?>
```

**Problem:**

Heading is shown but not any form element is shown. What am I doing wrong here ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's `__construct()`, not `_construct()`.

Comment: Yes you are right but now it proceed and generate another error: `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Controller_Response_Exception' with message 'Cannot send headers; headers already sent in /var/www/student/application/Bootstrap.php, line 28' in /var/www/student/library/Zend/Controller/Response/Abstract.php:321`

Comment: ok. I removed extra spaces after `?>`(php closing tag)  in **Bootstrap.php** and above error is removed. Now error is `Message: Method setLabel does not exist`....

Comment: Use $this->addElement('text', 'username', array('label' => 'Username'));

Comment: Ok. Using `$this->addElement('text', 'username', array('label' => 'Username'));` and using **init()** instead of **__contruct**, Two text fields are shown.. But labels are not shown.. May be there is something wrong with decorators.. Anyway thanks...

Comment: You don't see the labels because of: $this->setElementDecorators( array( 'ViewHelper' ) ); — only the <input/> itself is rendered. Try not setting the element decorators at all.

Comment: @Ivan Krechetov: Yes, you are right. Now labels are also shown. And my goal is achieved. Thanks. Can you tell one more thing please? Now form is shown but it is not looking nice. I have seen somewhere that a view script is defined/declared in Form class and then we render form elements in that view(.phtml) file in normal html format. Then we can place our form elements as we we wish. Do you know that how to achieve this. Thanks once again...

Comment: You're welcome. For explicit rendering you should do smth like this in your view script (.phtml), where the form appears: https://gist.github.com/822415

Answer (score 0):

Here is my complete solution:

Form Class in **Login.php**:

```
class Form_Login extends Zend_Form {

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct( $options = null ) {

        parent::__construct( $options );

        // Set the method for the display form to POST
        $this->setMethod('post');

        $elements = array();

        $element = $this->CreateElement('text', 'username');
        $element->setLabel('Username');
        $elements[] = $element;

        $element = $this->CreateElement('password', 'password');
        $element->setLabel('Password');
        $elements[] = $element;

        $element = $this->CreateElement('submit', 'submit');
        $element->setLabel('Login');
        $elements[] = $element;

        $this->addElements( $elements );

        $this->setElementDecorators( array( 'ViewHelper' ) );

        $this->setDecorators( array( array( 'ViewScript', array( 'viewScript' => 'authentication/login-form.phtml' ) ) ) );

    } // end construct


} // end class
```

**login-form.phtml**

```
<form action=<?= $this->element->getAction() ?> method=<?= $this->element->getMethod() ?> >


<table>
    <tr>
        <td><label><?= $this->element->username->getLabel() ?></label></td>
        <td><?= $this->element->username; ?></td>
    </tr>   
    <tr>
        <td><label><?= $this->element->password->getLabel() ?></label></td>
        <td><?= $this->element->password; ?></td>
    </tr>
</table>

</form>
```