# How to create a form in zend

Tags: php, zend-framework, forms

I am following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6006982/form-elements-are-not-shown/6022160#6022160) thread to create a form and it is working when No. of form elements are known. Now I have to create form fields based on user choice.

For Example:

```
<?php 

class Form_MyForm extends Zend_Form {

   public function __construct( $options = null ) {

        parent::__construct( $options );

        // Set the method for the display form to POST
        $this->setMethod('post');

        $elements = array();

        // Get user input to create elements
        $fields = $options['columns'];

        // Create form elements
        for( $i = 0; $i < count( $fields ); $i++ ) {
            $element = $this->CreateElement('text', 'field'.$i );
            $element->setLabel( $fields[$i]['name'] );
            $elements[] = $element;
        }

        $this->addElements( $elements );
        $this->setElementDecorators( array( 'ViewHelper' ) );
        $this->setDecorators( array( array( 'ViewScript', array( 'viewScript' => 'myform-form.phtml' ) ) ) );

    } // end construct


} // end class
?>
```

[I can render each element separately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6006982/form-elements-are-not-shown/6022160#6022160) but Now I don't know how to render these elements in myform-form.phtml by looping. I have to loop because No. Fields are not known at the begining..

Thanks

Comment: I'm not exactly a Zend_Form wiz (I actually hate it), but maybe you should move your code into another method (say `configureForm()` and have it accept an argument with the number of fields instead?

Comment: What is your `$columns` variable? I don't see where it is created.

Comment: @Marcin: Sorry it was typo. It is actually **$field** array. It contains Labels of form fields. For Example: `array('FirstName','LastName','BirthDate');` Please review the question again. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

should use something like this
(didn't test it)

```
<?
foreach ($this->element->getElements() as $element){
    echo $this->{$element->helper}(
        $element->getName(), 1, $element->getAttribs()
    )
}
?>
```

`$this->element` should be your form

Answer (score 0):

Side note to start: It's typical to do all this in the `init()` method rather than overriding the form constructor. But that's not really a big deal.

Re: rendering of the fields using the view script of `ViewScript` decorator: In `myform-form.phtml`, seems like you could call `$this->getOption('columns')`  and then perform a `foreach` loop to render the elements, analogous to the loop you used to create the fields.